# Javascript object property array, cant access the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

i am new to this, so i will try to explain as good as i can.i have a object with array property like this:

```
.factory('NewOrderData', function () {
        var order = {

            personList: []
        };

    return order;
})
```

when i try to call the property with this function.

```
this.ageCalc = function (person) {


    var currentYear = person;

    return currentYear;
}
```

I get this on the browser:
 [{"firstname":"Paul", "birthday":"1990-01-01"}]

I want to access only birthday. I've tried to put a dot after person like this person.birthday , but then the field is just empty

Can sameone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
[{"firstname":"Paul", "birthday":"1990-01-01"}]
```

...is an array with one element that is an object. So you need:

```
person[0].birthday
```

where `person[0]` gets the first (and only) element in the array, and then `.birthday` gets the birthday property of that element.

Answer (score 0):

As nnnnnn explained but to further clarify your doubt 
i want to explain working of object array

```
    var ob = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}];
```

if i want to access the value of second object's b than i should write

```
    ob[1].b;
```